# Calling to Functions that use Command Line Arguments

Tags: c

I am trying to call to function

```
int function(int argc, const char *argv[]) {}
```

from my main function with:

```
function(int argc, const char *argv[]);
```

But I am geting errors saying I needed an expression before int.

Comment: `function(argc, argv)`

Comment: You don't put type declarations in function calls, only in function declarations and definitions.

Comment: Just about any book, tutorial or class should have told you how to call a function with arguments.

Comment: @hmm doing that gave me even more errors than what I had before

Comment: @davidobravo that sounds like typical C progress.

Comment: @hmm actually it just gave me warnings, no errors. Do you know if the code still compiled despite warnings? Do only errors prevent code from compiling or warnings too

Comment: @davidobravo I'd consider warnings to be errors until you're able to fully understand the implications.

Comment: @hmm just forgot to include [] brackets on my char. No errors or warnings now. More typical c progress :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small program below maybe helps you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    function(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of test:

```
./test argv1 argv2
argc = 3
argv[0] = ./test
argv[1] = argv1
argv[2] = argv2
```

Comment: I got erors from this approach: warning type defaults to int in declaration of argv, passing argument 2 of function from incompatible pointer type,  and expected const char ** but argument is of type const char*

Comment: @davidobravo: Are you sure you copied and saved that code correctly?  You should not get those errors from this code.

Comment: How can you compile ? Are you sure that you copied and pasted well my example. i was using `gcc -Wall -Wextra` but no warning happen.

Comment: nevermind I miscopied my own code. Cheers.